# EmberJS: The best way to reload controller's model based on another property?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

What is the best way to reload model for a current controller based on another property?

For example: I have a post controller. Author can have only one post. I want to reload post creating form if currentAuthor property changes.

I've tried that way:

```
App.PostEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  modelReloadNeeded: Ember.observer((obj, keyName) ->
    postId = @get('currentAuthor').get('post_id')

    if postId?
      @set('model', @store.find('post', postId))
  , 'currentAuthor.post_id'
  )
```

It reloads everything, but returns not a real model, but promise.
And also it not looks like an idiomatic Ember solution.

Maybe there is any better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I believe reloading controllers model is equivalent to re-entering the same route. so there are lots of possibilities as of 2.12.0,

1. You can send action to route to **call [refresh](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_refresh)** on the current route

> Refresh the model on this route and any child routes, firing the beforeModel, model, and afterModel hooks in a similar fashion to how routes are entered when transitioning in from other route.

2. You can **specify dynamic segments** in url path and use transitionTo method in Route or [transitionToRoute](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_transitionToRoute) in controller.

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('posts');
  this.route('post', { path: '/post/:post_id' });
});
```

and you can say `this.transitionTo('post',123)` this will refresh the current route and you will get 123 as params in model hook.

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments
http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_transitionTo

3. You can **specify the queryParams** in the route and with refreshModel as true.

```
    import Ember from 'ember';
    export default Ember.Route.extend({
      queryParams: {
        postId: {
          refreshModel: true
        }
      },
      model(params) {
        //You will get query parameters value from the url through params.postId 
        return this.get('store').query('article', params);
      }
    });
```

You can even mention the same postId as queryParams in controller. it will refresh the route when you set `postId` property.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['postId'],
  postId: null, //here is the default value. default value will not be shown in URL.
});
```

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/routing/query-params/#toc_opting-into-a-full-transition

Answer (score 0):

I'm nervous to be giving you a solution to this problem, because I'm not sure you're approaching it correctly, however:

```
App.PostEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  modelReloadNeeded: function () {
    this.get('content').reload();
  }.observes('currentAuthor')
});
```

This should reload the `PostEditController`'s content property and therefore update your templates whenever the content's `currentAuthor` property changes.

Comment: yep, this will help, but I've a little bit more complex situation: controller was initialized with a new model `@store.createRecord 'post'` and I want it replaced with a loaded one, not just plain reload for a current model

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would find a different post and then set it as the content of the `PostEditController`.

```
App.PostEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  modelReloadNeeded: function () {
    // Find another post based on author id, tweak to suit your needs
    var otherPost = this.store.find('post',{ author_id : this.get('currentAuthor.id') })
    this.set('content', otherPost );
  }.observes('currentAuthor')
});
```

Comment: Using promise is more reliable.

    this.store.find('post',{ author_id : this.get('currentAuthor.id') }).then(function(post) {
      this.set('content', post );
    })

Answer (score 0):

`store.find` will return you a promise, so your should resolve it to avoid issues with no methods call

```
App.PostEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  modelReloadNeeded:(->
      postId = @get('currentAuthor').get('post_id')
      if postId?
        @store.find('post', postId).then (post) =>
          @set('content', post)
    ).observes('currentAuthor.post_id')
```